# How to create a Conditional foreign key in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
create table if not exists pgroup (
    id uuid primary key default gen_random_uuid(),
    label varchar not null,
    is_role boolean default false
);
```

I want to create a table like the following :

```
create table if not exists grouprole (
    groupId uuid not null references pgroup(id) `where is_role = false`,
    roleId uuid not null references pgroup(id) `where is_role = true`,
    primary key (groupId, roleId)
);
```

the idea is that two pgroup can be in a grouprole relationship if one is a role and the other is not.

My goal is that at INSERT time a check will be performed to ensure that.

EDIT:

I cannot split pgroup in two different tables because other tables references it and don't care for the is_role flag.

Comment: Why do you not use two reference tables for `roles` and `group`? In this case if you need you can create a view to get roles and groups - `create view view_group_and_role as select id,label,false is_role from pgroup union all select id,label,true is_role from prole;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use an auxiliary function in `CHECK` constraint:

```
create table if not exists pgroup (
    id int primary key,
    label varchar not null,
    is_role boolean default false
);

create table if not exists grouprole (
    groupId int not null references pgroup(id),
    roleId int not null references pgroup(id),
    primary key (groupId, roleId)
);

CREATE FUNCTION check_pgroup(p_id int,p_is_role boolean) RETURNS int AS $$
    SELECT id
    FROM pgroup
    WHERE id=p_id
      AND is_role=p_is_role
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

alter table grouprole add check(check_pgroup(groupId,false) is not null);
alter table grouprole add check(check_pgroup(roleId,true) is not null);
```

Test:

```
INSERT INTO pgroup(id,label,is_role)VALUES(1,'1',true);
INSERT INTO pgroup(id,label,is_role)VALUES(2,'2',false);

INSERT INTO grouprole(groupId,roleId)VALUES(1,2); -- Error
INSERT INTO grouprole(groupId,roleId)VALUES(2,1); -- OK
```

You also can create a cross-check into `pggroup` to prevent to set a bad value into `is_role`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_pgroup_is_role(p_id int,p_is_role boolean) RETURNS boolean AS $$
  SELECT true is_exists
  FROM grouprole
  WHERE ((p_is_role=true AND groupId=p_id) OR (p_is_role=false AND roleId=p_id))
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

ALTER TABLE pgroup ADD CHECK(check_pgroup_is_role(id,is_role) IS NULL);
```

Test:

```
UPDATE pgroup SET is_role=false; -- Error

INSERT INTO pgroup(id,label,is_role)VALUES(3,'3',true); -- OK
UPDATE pgroup SET is_role=false WHERE id=3; -- OK
```

Comment: @BlueMagma: be aware that `UPDATE pgroup SET is_role=not is_role`, for instance, will leave the other table with its constraints violated without any error occurring.

Comment: That is very bad advice. A check constraint must not depend on anything but the current row, even if you can use a function to work around that. For example, it is quite likely that you won't be able to restore that database from a `pg_dump`.